# How to uncheck checkbox when radio button is checked and uncheck radio button when checkboxes are checked using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div id="a">
  <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female
</div>

<div id="b">
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I have a bike<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">I have a car 
</div>
```

If checkboxes are checked then radio buttons should be unchecked and when radio buttons are checked, checked checkboxes should be unchecked.

```
             function uncheckDisabiltiesCheckbox(){
     var isChecked1 = document.getElementById('disabilitiesCheckbox1').checked;
     var isChecked2 = document.getElementById('disabilitiesCheckbox2').checked;
     var isChecked3 = document.getElementById('disabilitiesCheckbox3').checked;
     var isChecked4 = document.getElementById('disabilitiesCheckbox4').checked;
     var isChecked5 = document.getElementById('disabilitiesCheckbox5').checked;
     var isChecked6 = document.getElementById('disabilitiesCheckbox6').checked;
     var isChecked7 = document.getElementById('disabilitiesCheckbox7').checked;
     var isChecked8 = document.getElementById('disabilitiesCheckbox8').checked;
     var isChecked9 = document.getElementById('disabilitiesCheckbox9').checked;
     var isChecked10=document.getElementById('disabilitiesCheckbox10').checked;
             var isChecked11=document.getElementById('disabilitiesCheckbox11').checked;
             var isChecked12=document.getElementById('disabilitiesCheckbox12').checked;
             var isChecked13=document.getElementById('disabilitiesCheckbox13').checked;               


     if(isChecked1){
         document.getElementById('disabilitiesCheckbox1').checked = false;
     }
     if(isChecked2){
         document.getElementById('disabilitiesCheckbox2').checked = false;
     }
     if(isChecked3){
         document.getElementById('disabilitiesCheckbox3').checked = false;
     }
     if(isChecked4){
         document.getElementById('disabilitiesCheckbox4').checked = false;
     }
     if(isChecked5){
         document.getElementById('disabilitiesCheckbox5').checked = false;
     }
     if(isChecked6){
         document.getElementById('disabilitiesCheckbox6').checked = false;
     }
     if(isChecked7){
         document.getElementById('disabilitiesCheckbox7').checked = false;
     }
     if(isChecked8){
         document.getElementById('disabilitiesCheckbox8').checked = false;
     }
     if(isChecked9){
         document.getElementById('disabilitiesCheckbox9').checked = false;
     }
     if(isChecked10){
         document.getElementById('disabilitiesCheckbox10').checked = false;
     }
     if(isChecked11){
         document.getElementById('disabilitiesCheckbox11').checked = false;
     }
     if(isChecked12){
         document.getElementById('disabilitiesCheckbox12').checked = false;
     }
     if(isChecked13){
         document.getElementById('disabilitiesCheckbox13').checked = false;
     }
   }
```

Above is the code which unchecks all the checkboxes , when radio button is selected. How to get started with unchecking the radio buttons when checkboxes are checked.

disabilities.js

```
             $(document).ready(function(){

     $('#disabilitiesRadio :radio').click(function(){
           $('#disabilitiesCheckbox :checkbox').prop('checked', false);
     });

     $('#disabilitiesCheckbox :checkbox').click(function(){
         $('#disabilitiesRadio :radio').prop('checked', false);
     });
          });
```

Comment: How many boxes could the checkbox check if the checkbox could check boxes?

Comment: Could you show us what you have so far, perhaps in a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: I have written a javascript which unchecks all the checkboxes when radio button is selected.

Comment: @user2074252 is jQuery alright?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you were looking for:

## HTML:

```
<div id="a">
  <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female
</div>

<div id="b">
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I have a bike<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">I have a car 
</div>
```

## JS:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')){ //radio is now checked
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false); //unchecks all checkboxes
    }
});

$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')){
        $('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

## Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/24kg2/

Comment: I don't see a jQuery tag on this question.

Comment: I have this answer, but when i include this JQuery functions in jsp the function is not getting fired. I have included the necessary Jquery files but still its not firing .

Comment: @user2074252 You need to add `$( document ).ready(function() { /*code here */ });` Put the code above for `/*code here */`.

Comment: @j08681  $(document).ready(function(){
   
   $('#disabilitiesRadio :radio').click(function(){
      $('#disabilitiesCheckbox :checkbox').prop('checked', false);
   });
   
   $('#disabilitiesCheckbox :checkbox').click(function(){
    $('#disabilitiesRadio :radio').prop('checked', false);
   });
 });

Comment: @j08681 How to fire the above function in jsp file.

Comment: If run in it in fiddle its working fine, but when i include that in jsp its not get fired.

Comment: @user2074252 In your HTML file, import the jQuery JS file before your other JS file. Then it will be fired automatically. It works in the fiddle because jQuery is automatically imported.

Comment: I have included like this:                                           <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript" src="/trust/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript" src="/trust/js/disabilities.js"></script>    Still the function is not getting fired

Comment: @user2074252 Can you include your HTML file's header and the entire (or at least the breakdown of) disabilities.js in your original post?

Comment: @j08681 Please check the disabilities.js file

Comment: @j08681 After including the disabilites.js file in jsp file. Do i need to say anything like click next to div tag's inside jsp file.

Comment: @user2074252 Hold on, that's your entire disabilities.js file? And only include query.js and disabilities.js in the HTML file.

Comment: @j08681 Ya that's my entire disabilities.js. I have included the JQuery.js and disabilities in jsp file. Still it's not getting fired .

Comment: @user2074252 Are you sure you included the JS files correctly? It should work if you have the right jQuery JS file.

Comment: @j08681 Below is the error which is occuring when i click on checkbox or radio button                                        Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function disabilities.js:11
(anonymous function) disabilities.js:11
o.event.handle jquery.js:19
(anonymous function)

Comment: @user2074252 Problem with jQuery; get the newest jQuery.

Comment: @j08681 Thanks alot it worked. As you said it was an issue with jQuery.