# Toggle checkboxes with radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Building on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24268340/how-to-uncheck-checkbox-when-radio-button-is-checked-and-uncheck-radio-button-wh) I'm trying to use a radio button to check all checkboxes on toggle but if it's not toggled they should show unchecked or disabled. They control the layers on map the default should be all on and users can then remove them.

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7owytkad/5/) for what I've tried below;

```
$('input[value="energyRating"]').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')){ //radio is now checked
        $('input[id="check2"]').prop('checked', true);
        $('input[id="check"]').prop('checked', false);
        } 
        else { //radio is now checked
        $('input[id="check2"]').prop('checked', false);
        $('input[id="check"]').prop('checked', false);
        }
});
```

**Clarification:** in the fiddle if you click the extra radio button no checkboxes should be checked

Comment: You should never have multiple elements with the same ID

Comment: Other than the above comment about IDs (which you've "got around" by using `[id=]`) - your fiddle appears to do what you've asked.  Can you clarify the question with: what you're expecting to happen / what actually happens / what you are having difficulty with getting between the two.

Comment: Not sure what's wrong it's checking/unchecking the boxes as you toggle the radio buttons, is it not what you want?

Comment: Thanks all, have just add a clarification. If either of the two targeted radios aren't selected then no checkboxes should be checked.

Comment: You already have all the information you need to handle this scenario.  Are you having difficulty: adding an event handler / identifying the 3rd radio / toggling checkboxes?

Comment: Updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w35kbqfj/

Comment: You are still using duplicate id attributes. That represents invalid HTML.

Comment: @freedomn-m thanks, In total there are 7 radios, i could repeat what I've done for each and that will work but it seem's there is a better way if I can just say if this radio is not on then uncheck/disable the boxes rather than say what state for the boxes for each radio state

Comment: There are multiple ways to do what you want - eg have a single event for the radios, clear all checkbox, then add them using a switch.  or use data- attributes to pair the radio with its checkboxes.  Your question just asks how to do what it already does, adding new parts to the question via comments as each is resolved is not how SO questions work.

Comment: chek my answer bro it might help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is better to handle with class name when u have number of items.please check the below code it might help you to select all and reset all.

```js
$('.click').click(function() {
    //select all radio is now checked
        $('.event').prop('checked', true);
        $('.reset').prop('checked', false);
});

$('.reset').click(function() {
//reset radio is now checked
    $('.click').prop('checked', false);
        $('.event').prop('checked', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a">
  <input  type="radio" class="click" value="energyRating">select all<br>
    <input  type="radio" class="reset"  value="extra">reset
  
</div>

<div id="b">
  <input id ='check' type="checkbox" class="event"  value="Bike1">I have a bike<br>
  <input id ='check' type="checkbox" class="event" value="Car">I have a car <br>
<input id ='check2' type="checkbox" class="event" value="Bike">I have another bike<br>
  <input id ='check2' type="checkbox" class="event" value="Car">I have another car
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `id` attribute of an HTML element should be unique, so the repeated use of `check` and `check2` make your HTML invalid. I would just drop those `id` attributes.

One way to do what you need, and also avoid code repetition, is to mark the checkbox elements with data attributes which refer to the radiobutton for which it should be checked.

Here is how that would look:

```js
$('input[name="sex"]').change(function() {
    var selected = $('input[name="sex"]:checked').val();
    $('input[name="vehicle"]').each(function () {
        $(this).prop('checked', $(this).data("rating") === selected);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a">
  <input  type="radio" name="sex" value="energyRating">energyRating<br>
  <input  type="radio" name="sex" value="energyRatingByCount">energyRatingByCount<br>
  <input  type="radio" name="sex" value="extra">extra
</div>

<div id="b">
  <input type="checkbox" data-rating="energyRating" name="vehicle" value="Bike1">I have a bike<br>
  <input type="checkbox" data-rating="energyRating" name="vehicle" value="Car">I have a car <br>
  <input type="checkbox" data-rating="energyRatingByCount" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I have another bike<br>
  <input type="checkbox" data-rating="energyRatingByCount" name="vehicle" value="Car">I have another car
</div>
```